# Cannot get length of an array received as parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function in which I want to rearange all the 0 found in the array at the end and I'm using a temporary array . Everything is fine until I check the length of `testArray` which is the original array received as a parameter .Why I can't find out his length and how is the first `for` working if his length is undefined ?

```js
window.onload = function() {

var testArray =[5,3,0,55,0,9,0,8];
function moveArray(testArray){
  var tempArray= [];
  console.log(tempArray.length + " vs " + testArray.lenght);
  for( var i = 0 ;i < testArray.length; i++) { 
    if(testArray[i] != 0 ){
      tempArray.push(testArray[i]);
  //    console.log("pushed " + testArray[i]);
    }
  }
 // console.log(tempArray.length + " vs " + testArray.lenght);
    while(tempArray.length < testArray.lenght){
      tempArray.push('0');
     // console.log('push 0');
    }
    testArray=tempArray;
  for( var i = 0 ;i < testArray.length; i++){
  // console.log(testArray[i]);
  }
};  
  
  moveArray(testArray);
  };
```

Comment: do you just want to move the 0s to the  end or do you also want to sort the rest of the values'?

Comment: `lenght` **length**

Comment: testArray.lenght  ?    it should be testArray.length

Comment: check testArray.lenght spelling .it should be length

Comment: ok guys , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

you are using wrong spell in these lines

```
 while(tempArray.length < testArray.lenght){

console.log(tempArray.length + " vs " + testArray.lenght);
```

it should be

```
 while(tempArray.length < testArray.length){

console.log(tempArray.length + " vs " + testArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo with your "length", lenght should be length.
Secondly, you probably want to return your value.

Here is a working example:

```
window.onload = function() {

var testArray =[5,3,0,55,0,9,0,8];

function moveArray(testArray){
    var tempArray= [];
    for( var i = 0 ;i < testArray.length; i++) { 
        if(testArray[i] != 0 ){
            tempArray.push(testArray[i]);
        }
    }

    while(tempArray.length < testArray.length){
        tempArray.push(0);
    }
  return tempArray;
};  

console.log(testArray); // output: [5, 3, 0, 55, 0, 9, 0, 8]
testArray = moveArray(testArray);
console.log(testArray); // output: [5, 3, 55, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0]
};
```